# Cisco PrecisionHD USB Camera (Detected but no video)

Tags: usb, camera, hd-video, cisco

I'm having an issue with my Cisco PrecisionHD USB Camera.  It is detected but does not show video (using "Cheese Webcam Booth").  Any ideas? (I'm a newbie with ubuntu)

Specs:

- Ubuntu 12.10 32bit
- Dell Latitude E6400
- Cisco PrecisionHD USB Camera (USB 2.0) connected directly into laptop (no docking station)

Troubleshooting:

Using the command `lsusb`, I find the following device:

- Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1f82:0001 TANDBERG PrecisionHD Camera
- '+ more devices like audio, finger swipe, Linux foundation 2.0, 1.1

So what now?
Thanks.
MB

Answer (score 0):

Cheese webcam booth is not working at the moment. They said that they are trying to upgrade it. Try and use a different webcam viewer.